# Convert algebraic formula to CNF

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic

Consider the following test:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n{a_ib_ic_i} \overset{?}{=} q,\tag1$$

where $a_i, b_i, c_i \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$ and $q \in \{0, 1\}.$

Is it possible to rewrite [1] to conjunctive normal form?

Any help (links/toy examples/hints on how to start) is much appreciated.

Comment: It's a good way to right an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Courtois, Bard and Hulme](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2830) (section 2.2), you could approach this problem in two steps:

**Step 1:**
Solve the equation *modulo 2*. Take boolean variables. The equation becomes an exclusive or and can be readily converted into a CNF using tools like [bc2cnf](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/bcsat/#Tools).

**Step 2:**
For variables which were determined to be true/1 and thus unequal zero in step 1, find the sign. Again this is an exclusive or.

---

**Alternative approach**
If you require a solution in one step (and are prepared to deal with a far bigger CNF ...), you could model each variable as two boolean variables and translate your equation into a boolean expression as input for [bc2cnf](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/bcsat/#Tools).

Two variable encodings come to mind:
You could either encode the absolute value of the variable in one boolean and the sign in the second boolean:

[image]

As alternative, encode the variables as sums of -1 and +1:
[image]

Once you have encoded your triple-value integer variables in double-value boolean variables, you can take the logic for a [full adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29#Full_adder) and a [digital comparator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_comparator) to translate your equation into a logical circuit. The adder computes the sum and the comparator checks if the result stays between lower and upper bound.